# Why won't my command work in .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, file-io, cmd, duplicates

So my goal is to move a certain file type to one folder. Then in that folder find all the duplicates and delete them.

I came up with this:

```
for /r C:\users\ %%f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%%f" C:\test\ /y 
c:\tools\sfk sel -dir c:\test\ -file .jpg +dup +del!
```

The first part works, it moves all `.jpg` to a "test" folder but it then doesn't do the second part. The second part was made using SFK, it finds duplicates and deletes them in the cmd prompt but not in `.bat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You command will not work from batch file if delayed expansion is active, as the exclamation marks will get eliminated by the parser. Disable it before the `sfk` command

```
for /r C:\users\ %%f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%%f" C:\test\ /y 
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
c:\tools\sfk sel -dir c:\test\ -file .jpg +dup +del!
endlocal
```